# How to make a multiprocessing.Array process safe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, race-condition

While constructing a `multiprocessing.Array` the constructor takes an argument `lock`. It is default set to `True`

It is my understanding that when `lock` flag is set to `True` the `multiprocessing.Array` thus created should be process safe. However, i am not able to verify the behavior.

I am using the following code snippet to verify the behavior:

```
import multiprocessing
def withdraw(balance):
    for _ in range(10000):
        balance[0] = balance[0] - 1  
def deposit(balance):    
    for _ in range(10000):
        balance[0] = balance[0] + 1
balance = multiprocessing.Array('f',[1000],lock=True) ### Notice lock=True passed explicitly
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=withdraw, args=(balance,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=deposit, args=(balance,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
print("Final balance = {}".format(balance[0]))
```

Each time I run this code I am seeing different final results owing to race conditions affecting the run.

Can you please help me understand what I am doing and/or understanding wrong. As per my understanding, the code snippet I posted should always print 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock is not as atomic as you think.  It only wraps each individual read or write.   I reckon, in the gap between reading the current value and writing the new value, the other process has jumped in and saved a new value. Those changes are being clobbered when this one is saved.

There is a note documented against [Multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) which is insightful...

[image: Python 3.9 documentation]

If you bind both the read and write into a single transaction, with a `get_lock()` as described, it will meet your expections...

```
def deposit(balance):
    for _ in range(10000):
        with balance.get_lock():
            balance[0] = balance[0] + 1


def withdraw(balance):
    for _ in range(10000):
        with balance.get_lock():
            balance[0] = balance[0] - 1
```

For fun and understanding, you can wrap the `for` loops in the lock and watch it do *all* the withdrawals sequentially, then release the lock and do *all* the deposits sequentially thus:

```
def withdraw(balance):
    with balance.get_lock():
        for _ in range(1, 1001):
            balance[0] = balance[0] - 1
            sys.stdout.write(f'w {balance[0]}\n')
```

Comment: Yeah! I tried with lock placement in and out the loop and tried to see if I can create a process-safe update mechanism. I used a separate lock that I created with ```multiprocessing.Lock()```. I was able to do it. If the atomicity is not ensured then I think that the ```lock``` argument should just be removed and ```multiprocessing.Array``` should just be declared process unsafe and it should be the responsibility of the programmer to place locks in due places.